# WP7 Application Terminates with no exception, Databinding?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0

I have and application where I'm making multiple HttpRequests at start-up. It was working fine before I tried to move a lot of the UI handling to a different class in an attempt to be more of a MVVM application. Now when I'm loading the page with data my application crashes/terminates with no exception.

The main source of this termination (I believe) is where I'm setting the ViewModel for the RootFrame of the applicaiton so that I can reference it's classes in my xaml bindings.

```
    (App.Current as App).RootFrame.DataContext = (App.Current as App).ViewModel;
```

Without this the app will start but then none of my data is bound to the page. I'm guessing there are some asynchronous Http-calls that are changing the ViewModel at the same time it's trying to set that ViewModel as the data context of the RootFrame. I'm not sure if this would cause this kind of termination but I'm only guessing.

I'm pretty sure this part is what's causing the error because after it the app just shuts down, here is the output:

```
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'mscorlib.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.RuntimeHost.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Windows.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Net.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Core.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Xml.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\CCB2E631-D1D5-4AB0-B253-7B6CF6367D16\Install\ParkQuest.dll', Symbols loaded.
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\CCB2E631-D1D5-4AB0-B253-7B6CF6367D16\Install\Facebook.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\CCB2E631-D1D5-4AB0-B253-7B6CF6367D16\Install\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\CCB2E631-D1D5-4AB0-B253-7B6CF6367D16\Install\Microsoft.Expression.Interactions.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded 'System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
    'UI Task' (Managed): Loaded '\Applications\Install\CCB2E631-D1D5-4AB0-B253-7B6CF6367D16\Install\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll'
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1af811be) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1ada0ebe) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The thread '<No Name>' (0x1a9c105a) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
    The program '[457643138] UI Task: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

FYI my start-up Object is not the issue, as I have seen it is with some people.

Thanks in advance for your helpful suggestions and if you think there is a better way I should be implementing my data binding please let me know.

Also if you need any other information that would help you with answering this inquiry don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Configure Visual Studio to break on first-chance exceptions, you might learn more information on what's happening. In VS, press ctrl + alt + e, and activate the 'thrown' checkbox in front of 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are maybe having some problems with the timing...

Maybe you should implement some basic logging (request starts and finished, ....) to get a better look at the problem.

I have seen some problems with using WebClient and different parallel requests, maybe you should check this. As I know WebClient callback uses the UI threat, this can also be a problem when it happens to early (can be when your VM starts the request and gets initalized to early)...

Comment: If it's only a problem with WebCliet then I shouldn't have a problem since I only use HttpRequest (unless that uses WebClient).

Comment: WebClient uses HttpRequest internal (as I know)... If you want you can send me your code and i can have a look at it... hard to find such problems wihtout debugging it...

Comment: Yah, I've been spending a while trying to figure out the problem but it seems like it's crashing even before any HttpRequest are made. I'm pretty sure it's the data binding that's causing it. I believe I was calling a NotifyPropertyChenged event at the wrong time or something. I did a bunch of moving around my code and it seems to get past this hiccup now, it just isn't binding to the data.... alas it's a very strange problem.

Comment: Such things are always hard to discover... if you want me to have a look at it just ask ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps but I usually do this in the code behind to set the ViewModel for the view.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPageVMProperty = new ViewModels.MainPageViewModel();
}

public ViewModels.MainPageViewModel MainPageVMProperty { get; set; }

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    LayoutRoot.DataContext = MainPageVMProperty;
}
```